# subprocess for non-default shell command

Tags: python, linux, shell, subprocess

i have a problem with using subprocess. Here is what i wanna do: use python to open a shell, and call" bluetoothctl"(from bluez), then send/read other command, like"help",  under the 'bluez' program. However, the questions is that system does not know the 'help' command since its not supported by shell by default. It is supported by 'bluez'.
[image: here is what i wanna do]

my code:

```
import subprocess as sub
cmd_line = 'bluetoothctl'
cmd2 = 'help'

open_blue = sub.Popen(cmd_line, shell=True, stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.STDOUT)
out = open_blue.communicate()[0]
print (out)

open_blue = sub.Popen(cmd2, stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.STDOUT)
out = open_blue.communicate()[0]
print (out)
```

error said: `No such file or directory: 'help'`

im wondering what is wrong here. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the BlueZ stack at hand atm. to test, but provided that it works with regular STDOUT/STDIN, you can pipe STDIN, too, and use `Popen.communicate()` to send your command:

```
import subprocess

open_blue = subprocess.Popen(["bluetoothctl"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = open_blue.communicate("help")
print(out)
```

But if the `bluetoothctl` expects continuous stream (i.e. acts as a sub-shell) then `communicate()` might not be the right approach as it essentially waits for the subprocess to finish sending data to STDOUT, then sends your command to STDIN and closes it, and then waits for the STDOUT/STDERR and closes them as well - effectively making it useful for sending a single command to your subprocess. If you're going to be issuing various commands to the `bluetoothctl` process you might have to write your own handler for it. Something to the tune of:
    import subprocess

```
open_blue = subprocess.Popen(["bluetoothctl"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:  # lets wait for 'user' prompt
    line = open_blue.stdout.readline().rstrip()
    if line.endswith("#"):  # this is the prompt, presumably, so stop reading STDOUT
        break
    print(line + "\n")  # print the subprocesses STDOUT

open_blue.stdin.write("help\n")  # send the `help` command

while True:  # lets repeat the above process
    line = open_blue.stdout.readline().rstrip()
    if line.endswith("#"):  # this is the prompt, presumably, so stop reading STDOUT
        break
    print(line + "\n")  # print the subprocesses STDOUT

# now you can issue another command... and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

`bluetoothctl` reads commands and writes responses. Instead of creating a new process that tries to execute `help`, you should therefore write it to stdin of your `bluetoothctl` process.

I don't have this command available, but here's a complete, self-contained example with `python` itself, which also accepts a "help" command:

```
import subprocess as sub

p = sub.Popen(["python", "-i"], stdin=sub.PIPE, stdout=sub.PIPE);
print("The process said: " + p.communicate("help")[0])
```

When executed, you will get the python prompt and then this:

```
The process said: Type help() for interactive help, or help(object) for help about object.
```

This is exactly what you'd get if you typed `help` in a `python -i` prompt.

Comment: im wondering for the ["python", "-i"], what does the " -i " do here?

Comment: It makes Python start its REPL even though it gets data from a pipe instead of a terminal. Without it, it'll read a script instead of repl commands. Compare `echo help | python` and `echo help | python -i`